# How can I delete a namespace in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to delete the "testing" namespace. Which is the correct kubectl command for deleting it?

```
kubectl get ns                         
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   67d
ingress-nginx     Active   66d
kube-node-lease   Active   67d
kube-public       Active   67d
kube-system       Active   67d
testing           Active   21m
```

Comment: kubectl delete namespace testing? check https://phoenixnap.com/kb/kubernetes-delete-namespace for force deleting.

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest you to delete all resources inside the namespace.

After that...

```
kubectl delete namespace testing
```

If the namespace is "stuck":

```
kubectl patch ns testing -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```